# display list of days in a week in Rails using Date::DAYNAMES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having trouble displaying a list of days in a week in a form.

```
<%= form_for [@hourable, @hour] do |f| %>

  <% days = []
  Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index { |x, i| days << [x, i] } %>

  <% days.each_with_index do |day,index| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box day[0] %>
  </div>

  <% end %>   

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting error

```
undefined method `Sunday' for #<Hour:0x007fe13c764010>
```

But if I just display

`<%= day[0] %>`, it will give me a list `Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc... to Saturday`

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Replace

```
<% days = []
 Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index { |x, i| days << [x, i] } %>

<% days.each_with_index do |day,index| %>

<div class="field">
 <%= f.check_box day[0] %>
</div>
```

#### With

```
 <%= f.label :FIELD_NAME%>
<% Date::DAYNAMES.each do |day| %>
  <%= f.check_box :FIELD_NAME, {}, day %>
  <%= day %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to figure out how to add a `f.label` to this. When I try to do `f.label :day do`, with `f.check_box :day`, all the input name is the same. How do I change the name so label will match with input? If I'm keeping the same `:FIELD_NAME` or in my case is `:day`, it is going to be all the same throughout the loop.

Comment: label should come once while day comes seven times, I've edited the answer btw

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is calling `each_with_index` on `days`, since `days` is an array of arrays the way you've constructed it, where each element has the form `[dayname, index]`.

Instead of building up `days`, you can work off of the `DAYNAMES` array directly, or replace `days.each_with_index` with just `days.each do |x, i|` (but personally I think this is extraneous).

Also see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_day and [Rails non-table drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637787/rails-non-table-drop-down-list) if you're not tied to checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I had to `require 'date'` in `ruby 3.2.0` before trying to access its constants.